# Forking a subroutine that opens a socket pair

Tags: perl, fork, tk-toolkit, inet

I would like to fork a subroutine that opens a socket.

I have written the code to open a socket, receive the data, and print its received data. The GUI is written using
    [`Tk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk)

Below is the code, it does basically what I want to do, with the exception of not forking the `new_port` subroutine. Every time I click the `submit` button the `Tk` window gets stuck. I am looking for help with adding a `fork` to the `new_port` subroutine so it spawns a new child process. I personally have trouble with execution of the `fork` without syntax errors or not pushing the socket into a child process.

The idea is that I can fill in a new port in the form and hit submit. The window closes, I then press new again put a new port in and now a second socket is open at the same time as the first. e.g. port 1234 and 5678 are being listened to at the same time.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use IO::Socket::INET;
use Tk;

$myip = `ifconfig | grep -i inet | head -1 | cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -d " " -f1`;

sub new_port {

    my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
        LocalHost => "$myip",
        LocalPort => "$myport",
        Proto     => 'tcp' Reuse => 1
   );

    die "Cannot create socket on local host" unless $socket;
    print "Server waiting for client connection on port $myport\n";

    while ( 1 ) {

        my $client_socket  = $socket->accept();
        my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
        my $client_port    = $client_socket->peerport();
        my $input_data     = "";
        my $received_data  = "";

        do {
            $client_socket->recv($received_data, 65536);
            $input_data = $input_data . $received_data;
        } while ( $received_data ne "" );

        print "INPUT----------------------------------\n";
        print "Data from $client_address on port $client_port\n";
        print $input_data;
        shutdown($client_socket, 1);
    }
}

sub new_port_window {

    my $sw = MainWindow->new;

    $sw->geometry("200x100");
    $sw->title("port opener");
    $sw->Label(
        -text "Insert port #"
    )->place(
        -anchor => 'center',
        -relx => 0.5,
        -rely => 0.2
    );
    $sw->Entry(
        -bg => 'white',
        -fg => 'black',
        -textvariable => \$myport
    )->place(
        -anchor => 'center',
        -relx => 0.5,
        -rely => 0.4
    );
    $sw->Button(
        -text "submit",
        -command => sub {new_port}
    )->place(
        width   => 100,
        -anchor => "center",
        -relx   => 0.5,
        -rely   => 0.8
    );
}

my $mw = MainWindow->new;

$mw->geometry("150x100");
$mw->title("GUI TEST NEW FUNCTION");
$mw->Label(
    -text => "click new"
)->place(
    -anchor => "center",
    -relx => 0.5,
    -rely => 0.3
);
$mw->Button(
    -text => "NEW",
    -command => sub {new_port_window}
)->place(
    -width => 50,
    -anchor => "center",
    -relx => 0.5,
    -rely => 0.8
);

MainLoop;
```

Comment: Ah, since i am attempting to work out the forking i haven't added the 2nd half of the new port. But the overall idea was that a listening socket will be opened and a remote socket to another machine. All that data that comes in via the listening socket is sent out to the remote one. The idea is that multiple of these listening and sending pairs are setup and forked to multiple child process. So one pair per child process.

Comment: OK, so my (now deleted) comment wasn't so much off the mark (are you responding to it?) I still suggest to do this without the gui first.

Comment: Communication between parent and child would normally go via `socketpair` as mob shows you, what was the main point of my deleted comment.  If there are outside hosts involved then you can have another socket for that, presumably running inside the child process.  But then again, in that case there are various ways to do it.

Comment: Sorry yes was trying to respond, currently on my phone. Happy to try without a gui as i have a non gui version one but it just does one pair.

Comment: The `socketpair` provides for comms between a parent and a child; one child. If you have multiple then you'll need yet another component, `IO::Select` for instance, so that the parent can hop between those multiple forks (to talk to them) timely.

Comment: @ltstrom: "I personally have trouble with execution of the fork without syntax errors or not pushing the socket into a child process"* You should show the forking code that you have written and describe carefully the problems you are having. Stack Overflow is about *specific* programming problems, and requests to write the code for you aren't generally well received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time since I first tried this, so I forget if this is the way it has to be done or if it's just one of many ways that work, but the gist is:

1. create a socket pair before the fork
2. perform the fork
3. use one socket in the parent and the other in the child
4. if you want the socket to be unidirectional (from parent
   to child or child to parent only), call `shutdown` on the appropriate socket in both the parent and the child

Since you want to send data from parent to child only, it looks like

```
($sock_child, $sock_par) = IO::Socket->socketpair(
    Socket::AF_UNIX, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, Socket::PF_UNSPEC);
$pid = fork;
if ($pid) {
    # parent
    shutdown($sock_par, 0); # no more reading from parent
    print $sock_par $data_to_pass_to_child;
    ...
 } else {
    # child
    shutdown($sock_child, 1);  # no more writing in child
    $data_from_parent = <$sock_child>;
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Hey mob, how would this work with my script above i guess i would add your code to the new_port sub?

Comment: @mob: I've always used `close` rather than `shutdown` and I'm thinking [`shutdown`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shutdown.html) may be wrong as it *"also disables the file descriptor in any forked copies in other processes"*. This seems to suggest that the socket will be closed for both the parent and the child process, which *isn't* what you want.